# Convert string with '=' to JSON format

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I am trying to convert a string i receive back from an API into a JSON object in Angular.

The issue is that the string is not normalized to be parsed into JSON easily.

This is the string im working with:

```
"{rootCause=EJBusinessException: This is a sample exception thrown for testing additional info field, description=This is a more detailed description about the incident., stackTrace=com.springboot.streams.infrastructure.web.heartbeat.HeartbeatService.testServiceNow(HeartbeatService.java:200)}"
```

When trying to do `JSON.parse(myStr)` it throws an error due to invalid string format.

Is there an easy way to convert the listed string into a more correct JSON format, getting rid of the '=' and replacing them with ':' instead.

There is more to it than just `.replace(/['"]+/g, '')`, as even with that the string is not ready to be turned into JSON yet.

Hoping someone more versed in Javascript knows a trick i dont.

Comment: it's much easier to modify your API to make sure the response is always valid JSON/XML.. there are a lot of corner cases when you are trying to parse it in JavaScript

Comment: It is an API I do not have control over, so I cannot modify it unfortunately. @lastr2d2

Comment: if there are never any commas in the value portions, it's possible. Remove curly braces, split on the commas, then split on first = to get your pairs, and reassemble as a javascript object. Then stringify if you really need JSON

Comment: good luck with that... I worked with some similar scenarios and whatever solution I came up with it will always fail with the next corner case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to manipulate the string before parsing it remove unecessary string that can cause error to the object like "{" and "}" and split it by "," example is in below.

```js
var obj = {}, str = "{rootCause=EJBusinessException: This is a sample exception thrown for testing additional info field, description=This is a more detailed description about the incident., stackTrace=com.springboot.streams.infrastructure.web.heartbeat.HeartbeatService.testServiceNow(HeartbeatService.java:200)}" 

str.split(",").forEach((st, i) => {
 pair = st.split("=") 
 if(pair.length > 1) { 
   obj[pair[0].replace("{",'').replace("}", '').trim()] = pair[1] 
 } else {
  obj[i] = pair
 }
})

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

As commenters have posted, unless you control the API or at least have documentation that output will always follow a specific format, then you are limited in what you can do.   With your current example, however you can trim off the extraneous bits to get the actual data... (remove braces, split on comma, split on equals) to get your key:value pairs... then build a javascript object from scratch with the data... if you need json string at that point can just JSON.stringify()

```js
var initialString = "{rootCause=EJBusinessException: This is a sample exception thrown for testing additional info field, description=This is a more detailed description about the incident., stackTrace=com.springboot.streams.infrastructure.web.heartbeat.HeartbeatService.testServiceNow(HeartbeatService.java:200)}"

var trimmedString = initialString.substr(1, initialString.length - 2);
var pairArray = trimmedString.split(',');
var objArray = [];
pairArray.forEach(pair => {
  var elementArray = pair.split('=');
  var obj = {
    key: elementArray[0].trim(),
    value: elementArray[1].trim()
  };
  objArray.push(obj);
});
var returnObj = {};
objArray.forEach(element => {
  returnObj[element.key] = element.value;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(returnObj));
```